# How to return a string in response that have @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)?

Tags: java, json, maven, jersey, grizzly

```
@GET
@Path("/paises/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response findCuntryList(@PathParam("id")int id){
    try{
    ArrayList<Country> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<10 ;i++){
        Country c = new Country();
        c.setId(i);
        c.setName("country"+i);
        c.setCode("countryIsoCode"+i);
        c.setRegion("region"+i);
        lista.add(c);
        }

    Country co = lista.stream().filter(x -> x.getId()==id).findAny().get();
    if(id > lista.size()-1) throw new Exception("That id is not correct");
    return Response.ok(co).build();
    }catch(Exception e){

        return Response.status(404).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
```

I wanna return a json when i don't have a Exception but when i have it i need to return a string with the exception message but this drop error of json parse.

Comment: have you tried query param??

Comment: @RajanDesai no, sorry i'm learning this new tecnology. can you teach me or put some code. thx

Comment: for me..proper way of solving this problem is using **throw** under **catch** and make ExceptionHandler class using **@Provider** for that particular exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single quoted string is a valid JSON. So you could use:

```java
return Response.status(404).entity("\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"").build();
```

---

However I advise you to return a JSON object instead. It gives you the flexibility to return extra metadata about the error.

You could use a `Map<String, Object>`:

```java
Map<String, Object> errorDetails = new HashMap<>();
errorDetails.put("message", e.getMessage());
return Response.status(404).entity(errorDetails).build();
```

Or create a class for the error details:

```java
public class ErrorDetails {

    private String message;

    ...
}
```

```java
ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails;
errorDetails.setMessage(e.getMessage());
return Response.status(404).entity(errorDetails).build();
```

---

For reporting problems in an HTTP API, have a look at the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807).

Comment: now i dont have a parse error but dont showme the string i want

Comment: Yes, thanks  u are awesome man. with that code i realize that i have a problem with the exception message

Answer (score 0):

why are you not interested to use WILDCARD expression like,

```
 @Path("getSupportEmail/{broadcastMprId}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD)
    public Response getSupportEmailByBroadcastMprId(@PathParam("broadcastMprId") Integer broadcastMprId) {
        return Response.ok(broadcastMprBean.getSupportEmailByBroadcastMprId(broadcastMprId)).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sample code you provided and the tags for this question, you are probably better off using an Exception handler rather than catching and returning a hand-crafted message, and letting your `@GET` method return your domain object. The JAX-RS library (Jersey in this case?) will serialize it to JSON since your method is annotated with APPLICATION_JSON.

https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-en/cn/part1/chapter7/exception_handling.html

For Jersey specifically: https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jax-rs-jersey-custom-exceptions-handling-with-exceptionmapper/